# Convert values to Integer from serializeArray

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using serializeArray to take all input's values of form.

```
 let serialisedForm = $("#createProposal").serializeArray()
.reduce((a, x) => ({ ...a, [x.name]: x.value }), {});
```

But as a result I got:

```
name: "1",
name: "2",
etc..
```

How can I convert all values to integers?

Thank you.

Comment: try `parseInt(x.value )` on `x.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `parseInt()`?

```
let serialisedForm = $("#createProposal").serializeArray()
.reduce((a, x) => ({ ...a, [x.name]: parseInt(x.value, 10); }), {});
```